# Auto populate shipping address on CCAvenue payment page on Production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, populate, ccavenue

By default, On CCAvenue payment page, only Billing address is visible, on checkbox checked it shows empty shipping address form, rather than filled with info I sent in request(with same id and name as on payment page including checkbox for different address). I'm using ASP.Net MVC.

Same thing is working fine on UAT instance. I tried to contact CCAvenue technical support but they asked me to login on dashboard, which is not possible for me as it's manage by the Client.

Please suggest, How can I populate the shipping address **CCAvenue Payment page** for the Production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by analyzing CCAvenue Payment Page, there is hidden input fileld

```html
<input type="hidden" name="settingShippingInformation" value="Y" id="settingShippingInformation">
```

What needed to do is, Pass 'Y' along with other shipping information in this field.

```js
 $("#settingShippingInformation").val('Y');
```

It will populate the shipping fields with the provided values.

**Note:** As of now you cannot render checked/unchecked box for "*My Billing and Shipping address are different*". All you can do is, make it visible permanently from CCAvenue dashboard setting, according to CCAvenue Support:

> once you have logged in to the CCAvenue Dashboard >> go to settings >> Gaeway settings >> Shipping Address >> Select the option for "Allow your customer to specify a shipping address different than the credit card billing address?" as no.